# How to select and print out multiple items from an ArraryList? Java

Tags: java

I just made an ArrayList with a list of foods and I want to print out two foods from the ArrayList randomly. How do I do this?

I have looked on the internet and I've tried it. It works but when I duplicate it, it prints out the same food twice(always).

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int pizza = 1;
        int burger = 2;
        int fries = 3;
        int FishnCHips = 4;



        List<String> foodList = new ArrayList<String>();


        System.out.print("Which food do you want?");
        foodList.add("pizza");
        foodList.add("burger");
        foodList.add("fries");
        foodList.add("Fish and chips'");

        int randomIndex = (int) (Math.random()) * foodList.size();
        System.out.println("Two random foods : " + foodList.get(randomIndex));

        int secondrandomIndex = (int) (Math.random()) * foodList.size();
        System.out.println("Two random foods : " + foodList.get(secondrandomIndex));
```

All I really want is to print out two of the items from the ArrayList above. Nothing else.

Comment: Use the Random class and only one instance and then call nextInt twice

Comment: use `nextInt`https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, when you explicitly convert Math.random() * foodList.size() you'll always end up with 0. You can use Math.util.Random instead.

```java
import java.util.*;
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int pizza = 1;
        int burger = 2;
        int fries = 3;
        int FishnCHips = 4;



        List<String> foodList = new ArrayList<String>();


        System.out.print("Which food do you want?");
        foodList.add("pizza");
        foodList.add("burger");
        foodList.add("fries");
        foodList.add("Fish and chips'");

        Random rand = new Random();

        int randomIndex = rand.nextInt(foodList.size());

        System.out.println("Two random foods : " + foodList.get(randomIndex));

        int secondRandomIndex = rand.nextInt(foodList.size());

        while(secondRandomIndex==randomIndex){
            // To prevent both of the indexes to be the same
            secondRandomIndex = rand.nextInt(foodList.size());
        }

        System.out.println("Two random foods : " + foodList.get(secondRandomIndex));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to shuffle your list and get a sublist

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("pizza","burger","fries","Fish and chips");
Collections.shuffle(list); 
int randomItemsLength = 2; 
List<String> randomItems = list.subList(0, randomItemsLength);

System.out.println(randomItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem her is the casting. `Math.random` gives you a number between `0` and `1`. When you cast it to int you just remove everything after the decimal, so you end up with `0`. So it will return the first item in the list.

Using `(int) (Math.random() * foodList.size())` will hopefully give you a better answer.

You could also consider just using `Random().nextInt(foodList.size())`.

[This](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-generate-random-integers-in-a-range/) I think gives a good introduction to the different methods of getting random numbers in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in:

```
(Math.random()) * foodList.size();
```

You don't have parentheses around of the `foodList.size();`. This means you aren't modifying the `Math.random()` range. The line should look like this:

```
(Math.random() * foodList.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way to make sure you have 2 different numbers:

Create a list of integers from `0` to `foodList.size()`

```
List<Integer> indexes = IntStream.range(0, foodList.size())
                                 .boxed()
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Shuffle it

```
Collections.shuffle(indexes);
```

Pick the first 2 ones:

```
System.out.println("Two random foods : ");
System.out.println(foodList.get(indexes.get(0)));
System.out.println(foodList.get(indexes.get(1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the floodList.size inside the math.random parenthesis, you are always getting 0, so you show always the first food in your ArrayList

Try using this:

```java
Math.floor(Math.random() * foodList.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the correct cast would help.

```
int randomIndex = Double.valueOf((Math.random()) * foodList.size()).intValue();
```